# Not able to select value of field using jQuery when Multiple forms with fields having same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML page with multiple forms with different id's. Input box with same id exist in different forms.

I am trying to get the specific field from specific form.

I tried this:

```
 $j("#FormName #ID").attr("value")
```

Works fine in chrome, mozilla etc.. But this does not works in IE!

How to select the value of a field from a particular form.

Thank you.

Comment: same ID??? IDs must be unique

Comment: id's must be unique. convert it to class. `$j("#FormName .class").each(function(){alert($j(this).val();});`

Comment: using multiple id is not valid, however in some browser you may some result, as you shared this is not case for IE